# Dynamically loading and manipulating documents with Ember

Tags: ember.js, dynamic

I'm working on [an app concept](https://github.com/oakscastle/event/), and would like to know if Ember is suitable to the task.

I would like to go from a description of relationships between SVGs to a single SVG document.

The program needs to dynamically load documents, and recursively insert itself at the end of them.

So, from an object like:

```
[
  {
    id: 1,
    image: 'base.svg',
    contains: [
      {
        id: 2,
        position: { x: 50, y: 50 },
        size: { width: 35, height: 35 }
      },
      {
        id: 3,
        position: { x: 150, y: 150 },
        size: { width: 40, height: 40 }
      }
    ]
  },
  {
    id: 2,
    image: 'kitchen.svg'
  },
  {
    id: 3,
    image: 'den.svg',
    contains: [ {
      id: 4,
      position: { x: 25, y: 25 },
      size: { width: 10, height: 10 }
    } ]
  },
  {
    id: 4,
    image: 'tv.svg'
  }
]
```

To a page, `/areas/1`, like:

```
<html><body>
  <svg from='base.svg'>
    <!-- Contents of base.svg -->
    <a xlink:href='/areas/2'>
      <svg from='kitchen.svg' x='50' y='50' width='35' height='35'>
        <!-- Contents of kitchen.svg -->
      </svg>
    </a>
    <a xlink:href='/areas/3'>
      <svg from='den.svg' x='150' y='150' width='45' height='45'>
        <!-- Contents of den.svg -->
        <a xlink:href='/areas/4'>
          <svg from='tv.svg' x='25' y='25' width='10' height='10'>
            <!-- Contents of tv.svg -->
          </svg>
        </a>
      </svg>
    </a>
  </svg>
</body></html>
```

Comment: I don't see the question other than is ember suitable with SVGs. Yes. I've used it for making a lot of SVG components and have had great success. Some of it will work great with ember data, and some of it depending on complexity might be better handled with ajax calls. That all depends on your architecture and data

Comment: The SVG documents aren't going to be templates. The component would need to load the content and insert itself into that document for the children. That's not the usual pattern for Ember rendering.

Comment: Check some of the architecture of nf-graph (https://github.com/Netflix/ember-nf-graph/blob/master/addon/utils/nf/svg-dom.js)